# Hanging 20" x 16" glass pane

Tags: hanging, glass

I have a 20" x 16" glass pane (that is somewhere near a 1/4" thick) that needs hanging on a wall. The glass pane is actually a holographic image.

I remember seeing a compression/spring mechanism for hanging non-framed pictures that had clasps for each of the 4 sides of the shape and an X spring design to keep pressure even while providing a hookable mechanism some years ago but can't seem to find anything similar in a web search now.

What is the recommended way of hanging something of this size and weight these days?

Comment: Are you referring to a *plate hanger*?

Comment: Nope, glass pane, as in pane of glass (https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pane%20of%20glass)

Comment: Ah well, it did satisfy the four clips, a spring mechanism, and one point to mount it on the wall parts. I'm glad you weren't thinking of that as they are not generally aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: If this is a photo/art and you are looking to display it in your home (and don't like the DIY answers below consider taking it to a frame shop and as them how they will mount it for you. They will know how to do it "professionally" and you can decide whether to let them do it or look for the same hardware they use online.

Comment: @Stanwood - The 1 answer turns out to be what I was looking for, just didn't see (wasn't alerted via e-mail?) that the answer had been edited to include what I asked for and needed, to be sure [ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/18078) and I were thinking of the same thing. Answer now accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item you remember is called **Swiss frame clips** and still commonly available.

[image: Swiss clips] [image]

The other usual option is a standard method of attaching large glass objects to walls - **mirror clips**. Fancy or crude.

[image: Mirror clip] [image: Mirror clip]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I am struggling to find a picture illustrating the X shaped joining of the 4 fastenings I remember in the clip I described when searching with the term swiss frame clips. Might you have found a pic to confirm this is what I am describing? It certainly is preferable to hang the glass pane on one hook, rather than screw 4 things in the wall, as in the second suggestion.

Comment: I would search for mirror mounting clips since a glass pane is similar. This is if you can't find the ones above.